Path Error Information
How do I fix this? Unable to open CiviCRM to access databases:
Path Error Information:
The path for including CiviCRM code files does appear to be set properly. Most likely there is an error in the civicrm_root setting in your CiviCRM settings file.
Your CiviCRM settings file location is set to:
/home/wmm16qnuy38j/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
civicrm_root is currently set to:
Please check that your CiviCRM settings file is where it should be and that civicrm_root is set correctly in it. Also check that the CiviCRM code directory is where it should be. If these are both fine, then you will have to look in your logs for more information.

Welcome to SE!  Has this ever worked or is this a new installation?  If it is new, how far through the installation instructions are you?

This has worked in the past - for about the past 10 years. Now I cannot access anything, as this error message prevents me from being able to do anything. I have navigated to the settings page, but it is completely blank, so I do not know how I can update the path information. Please help!

There's not much to go with here.  Has it been upgraded recently? Are you the admin for it or do you have some other tech support?  You might be better getting on to https://chat.civicrm.org and asking there.  I'll respond if I see it.
